# Change text label asp net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, thread-sleep

How change text label in asp net visual basic while running procedures or functions. 
For example when project is validating something, the label say the same. (Excuse me,  I do not speak english)

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code of what you want to achieve? Currently your question is not clear.

Comment: I dont have code made, For example in the setup progress change the text while run procedures (extracting files...) I need do it in asp net

Answer (score 3):

**What I think you are trying to do:**
- Having a kind of status label with changing text which depends on the current task
- Executing procedures/functions on the application thread (by button clicks for example)

**How to handle it?:**
The way I`m doing it is the following:
Requirements:
- A *Timer* attached to your *Form*
- A Button and a Label (just for my example)

Here is the code how my approach would be:

```
private String currentStatus = "Idle";
    /*
    *   Use this while working with Lists or other kinds of arrays
    *   private object syncObject = new object();
    */
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Keep in mind that you should disable the button while the thread is running
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoTask)).Start();
    }

    private void DoTask()
    {
        /*
        *   If you are working with Lists for example
        *   you should use a lock to prevent modifications
        *   while actually iterating the list.
        *   Thats how you use it:
        *   lock(syncObject){// You can do it for a single or a bunch of list actions
        *       list.Add(item); 
        *   }
        */
        currentStatus = "Waiting...";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        currentStatus = "Scanning...";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        currentStatus = "Extracting data...";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        currentStatus = "Done!";
    }

    private void tickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = currentStatus;
    }
```

**Keep in mind:**
You cant change any *Control* values like *Label*.*Text* or others from other *Threads*! Thats why I use this *String* field.

I hope it helps :)